# Problem with calling a function?

Tags: c

If I have those functions:

```
void main(void)
{
    char *menu[] = {"data", "coming", "here"};

    prints(**************); // here

    printf("\n");

}




void prints(char **menu)
{
    int a;
    while(*menu)
    {
        printf("%s", **menu);
        menu ++;
    }

    a = 0;
}
```

How to call prints function ???

Comment: `prints(menu)`, but you forgot to add a NULL element at the end of your `menu` array, since that's what `prints` needs to know when to break the loop. Also it should be `int main()`, not `void main(void)` - and if your C compiler does not complain at the latter, throw it away and find a better one (e.g. gcc).

Comment: I'm going to start using `void main` in the obfuscated C contest -- it automatically blinds people to all other problems

Comment: Pavel Minaev tnx i will know that in future...
i meant how to call it from main i mean HOW TO CALL it to make it that menu array gets double pointer

so what i must put here
prints(**************); // here

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version with several issues fixed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// declare function before using it
void prints(char **menu)
{
    // make sure parameter is valid
    if (menu != NULL)
    {
        while(*menu)
        {
            // spaces so they don't run together
            // pass *menu not **menu to printf
            printf("%s  ", *menu);
            menu ++;
        }
    }
}

// proper return type for main()
int main(void)
{
    // array terminator added
    char *menu[] = {"data", "coming", "here", NULL};

    prints(menu); // here

    printf("\n");

    // return with no error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tnx really tnx for that explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

In C you must declare your function before another function that uses it. So...

```
void prints(char **menu)
{
    int a;
    while(*menu)
    {
        printf("%s", **menu);
        menu ++;
    }

    a = 0;
}

void main(void)
{
    char *menu[] = {"data", "coming", "here"};
    prints(**************); // here 
    printf("\n");
}
```

That, or you can forward declare the function:

```
void prints(char **menu);

void main(void)
{
    char *menu[] = {"data", "coming", "here"};
    prints(**************); // here 
    printf("\n");
}

void prints(char **menu)
{
    int a;
    while(*menu)
    {
        printf("%s", **menu);
        menu ++;
    }

    a = 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to flip those functions around?

Comment: haha yes, and I forgot to add a part about forward declarations.  Such a race on SO.

Comment: Tnx for your answer but i meant how to call it from main i mean HOW TO CALL it to make it that menu array gets double pointer

so what i must put here
prints(**************); // here

Comment: Well, considering that the code would not even compile, perhaps you should have posted some valid code?  There are other problems as well, look at the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can either move the `prints` function above `main`, or you can put a prototype for `prints` above main, like so:

```
void prints(char **menu);
```

Then, you can call `prints` from `main` just like any other function...